# How to show HTML and a table after expanding a table row in Ext Js

Tags: extjs, html-table, nested-table, extjs-grid

We are having a table with each row as expandable. 
When we expand the row, it will show one more table along with some Custom HTML.
Is this functionality can be achievable using Ext.Js ?

I saw some examples with nested tables, But how can we add Custom HTML along with the inner table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible with plugin: `rowexpander`.

Please refer to this: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/grid/grid-plugins.html